# Optimizing code to define variables only once, code only works when the vars are in change function and for the code outside change I redefine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, optimization

**Pretty sure I know the solution... would write .on('change','load', function(){}
correct?** <-- Tested didn't work? so I am up to your solutions :)

*Sushanth -- && adeneo both came up with great solutions, this is a good lesson in optimizing code... It's gonna be hard to choose which answer to go with, but I know this is going to help me rethink how I write... I dont know what I do without this forum, id have to learn this stuff in college.*

This is purely a question out of curiosity and bettering my skills, as well as giving you guys a chance to display your knowledge on jQuery. Also to prevent any sloppy writing.

I have a radio based switch box, the markup looks like this, the id's and on/off values are generated by the values in my array with PHP...

```
            <span class="toggle-bg">//This color is the background of the toggle, I need jQuery to change this color based on the state on/off
              <input type="radio" value="on" id="_moon_page_header_area1" name="_moon_page_header_area">//this is my on value generated by the array
              <input type="hidden" value="_moon_page_header_area" class="switch-id-value">// I create this input because I have multiple checkboxes that have the ID _moon_ARRAYVALUE_area1           
              <input type="radio" value="off" id="_moon_page_header_area2" name="_moon_page_header_area">// off value
              <input type="hidden" value="_moon_page_header_area" class="switch-id-value">//_moon_ARRAYVALUE_area2 
               <span class="switch"></span>// the switch button that changes
            </span>
```

Hope that makes sense and the comments are clear

Here is the jQuery

```
    var value = $('.toggle-bg input.switch-id-value').val()
var moon1 = $('#'+value+'1').is(':checked');
var moon2 = $('#'+value+'2').is(':checked');
var static_slide = $('._moon_staticarea_height');
var toggle = $('.toggle-bg');   

if(moon1){
    toggle.css({'background-color': '#46b692'});
    static_slide.hide()
} else 
if (moon2){
    toggle.css({'background-color': '#333'});
    static_slide.show()
}

$('.toggle-bg').change(function () {
var value = $('.toggle-bg input.switch-id-value').val()
var moon1 = $('#'+value+'1').is(':checked');
var moon2 = $('#'+value+'2').is(':checked');
var static_slide = $('._moon_staticarea_height');
var toggle = $('.toggle-bg');

if(moon1){
    toggle.css({'background-color': '#46b692'});
    static_slide.slideUp()

} else 
if (moon2){
    toggle.css({'background-color': '#333'});
    static_slide.slideDown()
}
});
```

it looks longer than it really is, its just repeating it self, one is on load so that it gives the correct color on load of the page, and then inside the change function we need to change colors..

How do I write it so I only have to use variables one time (so its cleaner) is there a better way to optimize it... Just NOW thinking after writing this I could put it in one function .on('load', 'change', function() {}

I just now thought of that, but I wrote all this so I am going to see what others think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do that by having the function in the change event handler, and on the end you chain on a `trigger('change')` to make it work on pageload :

```
$('.toggle-bg').on('change', function () {
    var value  = $('.toggle-bg input.switch-id-value').val(),
        moon1  = $('#' + value + '1').is(':checked'),
        slider = $('._moon_staticarea_height'),
        toggle = $('.toggle-bg');

    toggle.css('background-color', (moon1 ? '#46b692' : '#333'));
    slider[moon1?'slideUp':'slideDown']();
}).trigger('change');
```

As radiobuttons can't be unchecked, it's either `moon1` or `moon2`, which means checking one of them should be enough.

Comment: Interesting, it's cool there are so many ways to write the same thing in jQuery, I definitely like this solution it's less code and works well.. It's slightly new to me, I think mixing this code with a little of Sushanth's code could make for a pretty slick function write up...

Comment: Put it to the test and works very well... very lightweight, which I like and need to develop this kind of practice.. my jQuery code gets the job done but can be sloppy and heavy.. thanks, you are helping me become a better coder.. I appreciate it and hope you had fun writing a solution!

Comment: I went with this code, because its cleaner, we eliminate the if else statement and write the color change in one instance, also instead of writing slide up/down in two instances we write in in a .slideToggle callback... definitely learned something here.... hope it helps anyone else!

Comment: Actually I find I need to use the if/else statement with both (moon1)(moon2).. because if the toggle switch is off, I want the slider area to be shown.. by it being toggled, it is always closed no matter what...

Comment: Yeah I figured I would try and do something similar to how you wrote the color, but didnt want to fiddle with it... it results in a syntax error, the brackets arent playing nice..

Comment: Worked very well.. I haven't seen to many uses for brackets in jQuery, I am going to look that up.. might come in use again one day..

Comment: Compared to the original code this is soooo much more less writing.. looks good man.

Comment: It's just objects, so doing `$(element).fadeOut()` or `$(element)['fadeOut']()` is the same, but with brackets you can use variables or ternary expressions etc. but you're right, you don't see it very often as it's rarely needed, and a lot of people aren't even aware you can do it that way.

Comment: Yeah actually I saw someone talking about adding arrays in jQuery, I wasnt very interested and didnt pay too much attention to it, but it makes sense and can save a lot of writing..

Answer (score 1):

```
.on('change','load',
```

supposed to be

// Remove the comma separator if you want to bind the same handler to
// multiple events.

```
.on('change load',
```

And you can remove the one separately written out and enclose it in a function (if multiple instances of the class toggle-bg)

or just trigger the change event.(If there is a single instance of a class)

This will just run the same functionality when the page loads.

```
var toggle = $('.toggle-bg');

toggle.change(function () {
    var value = $('input.switch-id-value', this).val(),
        moon1 = $('#' + value + '1').is(':checked'),
        moon2 = $('#' + value + '2').is(':checked'),
        static_slide = $('._moon_staticarea_height');


    if (moon1) {
        toggle.css({
            'background-color': '#46b692'
        });
        static_slide.slideUp()

    } else if (moon2) {
        toggle.css({
            'background-color': '#333'
        });
        static_slide.slideDown()
    }
}).change();
```

Comment: This worked well and is much cleaner than mine, I definitely learned something here, there still are parts I have to keep looking at to completely comprehend but as of this typing looking at it its starting to make sense

Comment: I like how a set of variables can be defined with only one VAR instance, separating each by a comma.. definitely will use that again... I see the VAR toggle can be used inside the function as long as its the trigger element (think thats the right term) 

Only dont understand why .change(); is used at the very end.. I have seen this many times.. Re reading (This will just run the same functionality when the page loads.) that means it is necessary to run the function on load I am pretty sure!