# Set jQuery CSS Variable Only Once

Tags: jquery, var, stoppropagation

This addresses my issue somewhat, but not entirely:

[Optimizing code to define variables only once, code only works when the vars are in change function and for the code outside change I redefine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537629/optimizing-code-to-define-variables-only-once-code-only-works-when-the-vars-are)

It's a pretty elementary requirement -- I want to get a class' text color when an element is dynamically loaded. No problem there:

```
var follColor = $('div.followup').css("color");
```

And when a certain condition is met, I want to update any class with that color, which references the state of the application I'm working on:

```
$('.anyclass').attr('style', 'color:'+follColor+'');
```

The problem is that a variety of conditions can and do occur that will change that text's color dynamically after the page is loaded -- I'll never know which. I just want to get that initial state that can be initially set by a user and have it applicable without ever having that `follColor` variable reset.

The simplest solution would be to somehow prevent the var from ever being updated after that first time. As suggested, there really isn't any event to bind it to that would, for example, stop propagation/resetting. I'm stumped and can really use some help here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly try this. You want it that if follColor has a value it shouldn't change, so instead of simply setting it try this:

```
var follColor;
if(follColor == null){
  follColor = $('div.followup').css("color");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Helps, except the result is "undefined," not "null," and which would require three `=` signs, or else `follColor == undefined` would also accept "null" as a response. I also saw some synchronization issues -- alot of processes I don't have access to hit the application throughout any given session -- so I finally decided to wrap it all in a `$(document).ready`. You definitely pointed me in the right direction and quickly, so thanks very much. My answer is below.

Answer (score 0):

cbender's reply got me going in the right direction, but the woroking answer required I wrap the setting in a `$(document).ready` function to prevent event propagation. Here's what worked:

```
      $(document).ready(function(e) {
          var follColor;
          if(follColor === undefined){
            follColor = $('div.followup').css("color");
          } else {
            e.stopPropagation;
          }
      });
```